# Will adding 40,000 301 redirects slow down a site?

Tags: permalinks

Will 40,000 301 redirects slow down a site?
The 301 redirects will be from within the same site.

-- Additional info --

We're using a plugin for this (Redirection WP) and the author mentioned this regarding the performance "The plugin works in a similar manner to how WordPress handles permalinks and should not result in any noticeable slowdown to your site."

Another thing too is he said "Apache .htaccess is not required - works entirely inside WordPress"

Comment: Most likely, but hard to say how much. What kind of redirects: written in PHP, htaccess, nginx or something else? Can you give an example?

Comment: @birgire We're using a plugin for this (Redirection WP) and according to the author "Apache .htaccess is not required - works entirely inside WordPress". Another thing the author mentioned regarding the performance of the plugin "The plugin works in a similar manner to how WordPress handles permalinks and should not result in any noticeable slowdown to your site."

Answer (score 1):

It depends, if the plugin manually redirects each one of the links then it may slowdown. But, if is using regular expressions and then you end up with a few rules that handles all the redirection then it's not a problem.

Comment: For this plugin, I'm manually putting in the redirects in one by one without any rules.

Comment: Take a look at this one also: https://wordpress.org/plugins/quick-pagepost-redirect-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation, Emanuel. What's the difference between Redirection Wordpress and your recommend plugin?